# How to make the input refuse negative values and print specifically the statement to have when negative

Tags: python, while-loop, python-requests

Currently, when I enter a negative value it will print "Input data not in correc format - try again". However, I want it to print the statement "The value cannot be negative". I tried adding that as an extra condition but it won't work. Any suggestions on what to try?

```py
bookTotal = 0
books = "n"
price = float(input("Enter the price for this book: "))
while books != "exit":
    books = input("Enter the number of books ordered by this customer: ")
    if books.isdigit():
        books = int(books)
        bookTotal = bookTotal + books
        income = bookTotal * price
    else:
        print("Input data not in correc format - try again")
    if books == "exit":
        print("Data entry is complete")
        print("The total number of books ordered is",bookTotal,'.')
        print("The total income generated from this book is $",income,'.')
        print("Program terminated normally")
    elif books < 0:
        print("Cannot be negative")
```

Comment: Your variable `books` is currently a string. When you check whether `books.isdigit()`, cast it to an `int`. Now you can check `if books < 0`

Comment: User a `while True` instead of a conditional one.

Comment: User `str.format()` also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from the comment:

```
bookTotal = 0
price = float(input("Enter the price for this book: "))
income = 0

while True:
    userInp = input("Enter the number of books ordered by this customer or Enter Q/q to exit: ")
    if userInp.lower() == "q":
        print("Data entry is complete")
        break
    if int(userInp) > 0:
        bookTotal = bookTotal + int(userInp)
        income = bookTotal * price
    else:
        print("Cannot be negative or 0")
print("The total number of books ordered is {}.".format(bookTotal))
print("The total income generated from these books: $ {}.".format(income))
print("Program terminated normally")
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Enter the price for this book: 23.50
Enter the number of books ordered by this customer or Enter Q/q to exit: -1
Cannot be negative or 0
Enter the number of books ordered by this customer or Enter Q/q to exit: 0
Cannot be negative or 0
Enter the number of books ordered by this customer or Enter Q/q to exit: 5
Enter the number of books ordered by this customer or Enter Q/q to exit: 10
Enter the number of books ordered by this customer or Enter Q/q to exit: q
Data entry is complete
The total number of books ordered is 15.
The total income generated from these books: $ 352.5.
Program terminated normally
```

Answer (score 0):

`isdigit()` will return False if your string contains anything other than numbers. ("-1" contains a '-', therefore it returns false and you get the incorrect format message.)

I'd try something like this...

```
if books.isdigit()
    # ...
elif books[1:].isdigit() and int(books[1:]) < 0:
    # ...
elif books == "exit":
    # ...
else:
    print("Input data not in correct format.")
```